# How to speed up the process of catching up until the offset at XXX

Tags: confluent-schema-registry

In my case, 950 offsets take more than 2 minutes. How to speed it up?

The time taken can be seen as follows:

`[2020-03-02 10:18:13,871] INFO Wait to catch up until the offset at 950 (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStore)

[2020-03-02 10:20:34,931] INFO 10.244.5.1 - - [02/Mar/2020:10:20:33 +0000] "GET /config HTTP/1.1" 200 0  1822 (io.confluent.rest-utils.requests)`

My environment:

- `confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:5.4.0`
- `SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HEAP_OPTS=-Xmx812m -Xms600m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16M -XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=50 -XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=80`